# jQuery 'each' shorthand

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, each

Is there any way I can short hand jquery each? or is there any alternative in writing jquery each which is shorter than the code below?

```
$('someElement').each(function () {
    functionName('value1', value2)
});
$('anotherElement').each(function () {
    functionName('value1', value2)
});
$('andMoreElement').each(function () {
    functionName('value1', value2)
});

functionName(foo, element){
   //function code here
}
```

Comment: Give them the same class like `$('.thesameClass').each(function() { });`

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: what is `foo` and `otherfoo` - where do they come from? you could put them into a data attribute on the element and then just call one loop passing the data attrbute into `functionName`

Comment: `$('someElement').each(functionName)` would be shorter if the function didn't need any parameters.

Comment: every time functionName is called, there is a unique value for parameters foo and element.

so eachtime I call functionName inside each statement, chances are values are different from the others. I wanted to know if theres any way I can shorthand each like you short hand the "if" condition statement

Comment: You keep changing the question. Note that whenever you change the question, you invalidate the answers people have been kind enough to provide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of the ***latest*** version of the question, where all three `each` use the same values, you're best off either using a comma-series of selectors (if those are selectors), or the `add` function (if they aren't):

```
$('someElement, anotherElement, andMoreElement').each(function () {
    functionName('value1', value2)
});

functionName(foo, element){
   //function code here
}
```

or

```
$('someElement').add('anotherElement').add('andMoreElement').each(function () {
    functionName('value1', value2)
});

functionName(foo, element){
   //function code here
}
```

Again, it depends on whether `'someElement'`, `'anotherElement'`, and such are selectors or elements.

Because you're using `each`, which calls the function right away, you can *also* use the `curry` option below. If you were using `click` or similar, using the `curry` option below would change when `value2` was evaluated (from when the function is called to when it's curried), which may be desirable or undesirable depending on your use-case.

---

**Answer for an earlier version of the question**:

Sadly, you can't use `$.proxy` or `Function#bind` for this, as both of them will change the value of `this` in the call. You can create a [`curry` function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) that reuses the `this` it was called with:

```
var slice = Array.prototype.slice;
function curry(f) {
    var args = slice.call(arguments, 1); // Copy args after `f`
    return function() {
        return f.apply(this, args.concat(slice.call(arguments, 0)));
    };
}
```

When you pass a function and X number of arguments into `curry`, it returns a function that, when called, will call the original function with the `this` value it was called with, the arguments provided to `curry`, and then any arguments provided to the call.

Then:

```
$('someElement').each(curry(functionName, 'foo'));
$('anotherElement').each(curry(functionName, 'otherFoo'));
$('andMoreElement').each(curry(functionName, 'otherFoo'));

functionName(foo){
   //function code here
}
```

Or as the second two uses have the same argument:

```
$('someElement').each(curry(functionName, 'foo'));
$('anotherElement, andMoreElement').each(curry(functionName, 'otherFoo'));
// Or:
$('anotherElement').add('andMoreElement').each(curry(functionName, 'otherFoo'));

functionName(foo){
   //function code here
}
```

Comment: Hi T.J. as a pro I really admire, I will really appreciate if you will comment if you see a need on my Q&A here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18749924/601179

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to expand the selection, you might be interested in the `.add()` function:

```
$('someElement').add('onotherElement').each(function() { })
```

will apply your logic to all matches of the `someElement` as well as `onotherElement`

Answer (score 1):

```
 $('#onotherElement','#someElement').each(function () {
        functionName('foo')
    });
```

Comment: That doesn't do what you think it does / what the OP wants. That looks for `#onotherElement` **within** `#someElement`. See [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1).

Comment: every time functionName is called, there is a unique value for parameters foo and element. so eachtime I call functionName inside each statement, chances are values are different from others. I wanted to know if theres any way I can shorthand each like you short hand an "if" condition statement

Comment: no it doesn not look for onteherelement within someelement...
u can add how many ever elements u want from any part of the page
.each will get called each time..

Comment: $(document)
.ready(
  function() {
$( "#autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
  source: [ "c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby" ]
});

$("#but","#cut").click(function(){
 $('#autocomplete').autocomplete( "close" );});});
see this sample code #cut and #but are two buttons click function is called if any of the button is clicked

Comment: It does look for one within the other. To look for either element you have to pass a single string with the comma _inside_ the string, like this: `$('#onotherElement,#someElement')`

Comment: @user2256955: *"no it doesn not look for onteherelement within someelement"* Again: Read the documentation. If you don't believe that, maybe an example would help: http://jsbin.com/UwumUBU/1

Answer (score 1):

Edit: this will allow you to pass parameters through as per the edit in your question.

```
var a = 'Function', b = 'works';

$('.a').each(foo.bind(this, a + 'foo', b + 'foo')); // (1)

function foo(a, b, i, el) {
  console.log(a, b, $(el).text());
}
```

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZgUn7/2/)

(1) I added foo to the vars to prove that `foo` isn't picking up the globals, but the parameters that are passed in.